# How to identify anonymous types in JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am writing one function on Javascript which needs to address all the anynymous types in a JSON object.

For example,

```
Typed=  {
 emails: [{email:'a@a.com'}, {email:'b@a.com'}, {email:'c@a.com'}, {email:'d@a.com'}]
};
```

is an example of typed array in a JSON because each element inside the array is typed `email`

while,

```
Anon=  {
 emails: ['a@a.com', 'b@a.com', 'c@a.com', 'd@a.com']
};
```

is a JSON object where emails is collection of some anonymous objects.

Is there any ways that I can differentiate between both in JQuery or Javascript?

Comment: There is no such things as **anonymous type** in JSON.

Comment: You would have to write code that tries to detect which one it is, it more than likely won't be a very automatic process. `if (json.emails[0].email) { /* it's array of objects */ } else { /* it's array of values */ }`

Comment: In that case in Typed each element in emails would have a TYPE called email and in ANON would not have anything..... that is the difference...

Comment: That's not JSON, strictly speaking. Property names and values must be double-quoted in real JSON. If this is just supposed to be JavaScript object literal notation, well carry on then :-)

Comment: @Kevin : The problem here is that this is going to be a generalized function and all it is supposed to know is that incoming element is a JSON and that's it. So I can not be specific such as json.emails[0].email because it is emails[0] at this moment but it might change depending on JSON soming in

Comment: So, you want a snippet of code that can automatically loop through json no matter what it's structure is. I don't think that is possible unless you write it to check for all the different possibilities similar to the code I posted, however, those possibilities could be endless if even the text email could be different.

Comment: @Pointy: I am sorry if I was not good enough with my notations and syntax but point that I am trying to convey is basically same rather it's Javascript notation or JSOn object

Comment: Yes I understand - don't take it as an attack on your question. StackOverflow is a repository of answers to questions, so things like that have to be clarified for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: ohh sure.. don't worry I should had been more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to have the JSON source only return one of the two forms.  Then you don't have to branch in your client.

If that's not an option, you could get the values out with JavaScript's handy lazy-evaluation of boolean expressions:

```
var em = json.emails[0].email || json.emails[0];
```

That statement will prefer the array-of-objects version, but use the array-of-strings version as a fallback.

(edited in response to clarifying comment below)

You can determine what properties a JS object has at runtime like this:

```
function enumerate(targetObject){
    var props = [];
    for (var propName in targetObject ){
        props.push(propName);
    }
    return props;
}

console.log(enumerate({foo:1, bar:'baz'}),join(',')); //"foo, bar"
```

you could then modulate your logic on the basis of the properties you get back.  You'll want to make sure you understand prototypes (specifically what `Object.hasOwnProperty` does and means), too.

Comment: I see your point, but the problem here is that my final goal is not to read the value from it. but to identify whether it is an Anonymous or not. Again we don't know the structure or name of incoming JSON offhand so we don't know whether it is going to be json.emails[0].email  or json.emails[0].Firstname.. you see?

Comment: by your logic, all JS objects are anonymous:  there's *no such thing as a type in JavaScript*.  that said, I've edited my answer to give you a mechanism for determining what properties an object has.

Comment: I think @Californicated just made his own types up using an object. He knows it's not a type, but it may be useful for him somehow. Take a look at my answer I think it correctly identifies what is meant by anonymous and typed objects in this question.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var istyped = function (a) {
  if (typeof(a) !== 'object') {
    return false;
  }

  var count = 0;
  for (var key in a) {
    count = count + 1;
  }

  return (count === 1);
}
```

I'm assuming here you just want to distinguish between regular variables (this would be your anonymous variable) and objects with just one key/value pair inside (this would be your typed variable).

To check if array contains only typed variables you'd just have to loop through it with that function. For example (in newer versions of JavaScript):

```
Typed.emails.every(istyped) = true
Anon.emails.every(istyped) = false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array [iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) to quickly check if all (or some) elements of the array have the desired type:

```
Anon.emails.every(function(e) { return typeof e == "object" }) // false
Typed.emails.every(function(e) { return typeof e == "object" }) // true
```

or a more generic solution

```
typeCheck = function(type) { 
    return function() {
        return typeof arguments[0] == type
    }
}


Anon.emails.every(typeCheck("object")) // false
Typed.emails.every(typeCheck("object")) // true
```

(An obligatory warning about iteration methods not being supported in [ancient browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Browser_compatibility))

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a map first:

```
emails = emails.map(function (email) {
    if (typeof email.email === 'string')
        return email.email;
});
```

That will make your emails array an array of just strings. Then you can just process it as usual. There aren't any side-effects if it is an array of strings (`email.email` will be undefined).

I do stuff like this when I have to make one client deal with multiple versions of an API. Alternatively, you could do the map the other way:

```
emails = emails.map(function (email) {
    if (typeof email === 'string')
        return {email: email};
});
```

This would work better if there could be other information in each object in your emails array.

Comment: Just a note here, this only works in JavaScript 1.6. If you need compatibility, you may need to implement some stuff yourself. It's not too hard though, just add your mapping function to `Array.prototype.map`